# ArcGIS Javascript API - Looking For Styled Navigation Plugin/Widget

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am looking for a fancy navigation plugin to use with the ArcGIS Javascript API.  Something along the lines of the Navigation Widget (see image below) available in the Flex Viewer would be great.

Anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

[image: Navigation Widget]